# multi Boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataset, boxplot

How I can do a multi boxplot in R with the heights of basketball player divided by position (G, F, C) for decade
My dataset called player is this:

```
name = c("Kareem", "MJ", "Lebron")
year_start=c(1970, 1985, 2003)
year_end=c(1989, 2003, 2018)
position=c("C", "G", "F")
height=(219, 198, 203)
player<-data.frame(name, year_start, year_end, position, height)
```

my idea is like this

[image]

help me please

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! instead of pasting your dataset as an image, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset that everyone can copy/paste it will makes things easier for people to help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: have you try `ggplot(player, aes(x = position, y = height)) + geom_boxplot()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't wrong anymore, your solution works, by my idea is divide the year in decade and for every decade have the boxplot for G-F-C (i didn't say it, sorry again), my ide a for divide the years is:  year_start<=1959 & year_end>=1950

Comment: Ok, I see. so please update your question with a reproducible example according my first comment.

Comment: now is ok? sorry but I'm clumsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reproducible example is a little bit too short so I made one allowing to have each group for each decades

So, if you want to represent the boxplot of the height of players per decade you need first to attribute a decade to each players.

You can do it for example by rounding the starting year to the floor decade by doing:

```r
player <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:20],
                     year_start = c(sample(1970:1979,10, replace= TRUE),
                                    sample(1980:1989,10,replace = TRUE)),
                     height = sample(180:220,20, replace= TRUE),
                     position = sample(c("P","G","C"),20, replace = TRUE))

player$decade = floor(player$year_start  %/% 10) * 10
```

Now, you can use it to create your boxplot as follow:

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(player, aes(x = as.factor(decade), y = height, fill = position))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: nope, beacause give me only 3 plot and not 3 for every decade

Comment: I forget to add `as.factor()` into the `aes`. I edited my answer accordingly. Let me know if it is working

Comment: and the player can play in multiple decades, how can show that he played in more decades?

Comment: However it works, thanks you very much, if you want help me for problem of decade thanks you again